# Trigger alert BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to set up a notification system (mail) which will run when a value in my table exceeds a threshold.

I don't know if it's possible but if it's help this data will be used by Google Data Studio, so if there is a feature that do the same that I want it's not a problem for me. Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide an example to clarify your question?

Comment: Np, so I have a table and in this table I have a row with "indicator_name" and "value", I want when value is greater than 6 I receive a notification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative solution.
These is no trigger support for BigQuery. You can try below steps to attain similar features:

1. Create a Cloud function to read the specific table and check for the “indicator” value > 6 and send a mail once it crosses the threshold value. Here is the link for [sending email from cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid)
2. Create a Cloud scheduler to invoke a Cloud function as per required frequency (Example: every 3 mins)

Comment: Thank you I will try it